# SQL on pull rows where id is < #

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to query my table and return all results less than a specific #

```
dayid km
  1   5
  2   5
  3   5
  4   5

SELECT COUNT(km) FROM travel HAVING COUNT(dayid) < 3
```

This should only count rows 1 & 2 and thus returning the sum of KMS (10) however I am returning 0 rows

Comment: `count(dayid)` is going to be 4, since there's 4 rows. You don't have any `group by` clause, so mysql is free to group on the ENTIRE table. since `4 < 3` is false, you get nothing back.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select sum(km)
from travel
where dayid < 3
```